# Build Security Token Service (STS) application for ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, sts-securitytokenservice

I have a ASP.NET based CMS which i use to setup websites. This CMS uses a standard ASP.NET membership mechanism, and it can work with claims based / STS authentication.

Now i want to setup a set of 4 websites and a login page/portal that sits in front of these websites, which users can use login to one of these websites. During the login process some database setting has to determine to which website the user has to be logged in and redirected to.

Is there some project or code example anyone can give which i can use as a start to develop such a STS service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WIF 3.5 SDK has a sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748478.aspx). Download the sdk and install the sample by copying it into the templates folder for VS.

Thinktecture has a sample .NET 4.5 STS [here](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2)

There is also a WIF 4.5 example STS in [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Federation-Metadata-34036040) sample

Comment: All this 3.5 stuff seems to be deprecated. And also when i search for the 4.0/4.5 version of this, i seems that i'm looking at examples which are already deprecated.

Comment: Does anyone have a recent, .NET 4.5 based, example for building a custom STS?

Comment: See the thinktecture example headline: 'Thinktecture IdentityServer is a light-weight security token service built with .NET 4.5, MVC 4, Web API and WCF.'

Comment: It took some time to get this thing up and running, but by now the Thinktecture server does seem to be what we were looking for. Thanks!